# How do I check instanceof [Ljava.lang.String?

Tags: grails

What is `[Ljava.lang.String` as an object where I can do an instanceof check on it?

```
params['specialTypeInd[]'] instanceof *What goes here*
```

`params['specialTypeInd[]']` is the array of strings. `[Ljava.lang.String` is its class.

Answer (score 1):

It's an array, in this particular case array of Strings.

```
def a = [1,2,] as String[]
assert a instanceof String[]
```

Comment: Ahh okay, I didn't know I could do that. Thanks